# conditional change of a pandas row, with the previous row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the following pandas dataframe, I want to change each row with a "-1" value with the value of the previous row. So this is the original df:

```
   position  
0     0        
1     -1        
2     1
3     1
4     -1
5     0
```

And I want to transform it in:

```
   position  
0     0        
1     0        
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     0
```

I'm doing it in the following way but I think that there should be faster ways, probably vectorizing it or something like that (although I wasn't able to do it).

```
for i, row in self.df.iterrows():
    if row["position"] == -1:
        self.df.loc[i, "position"] = self.df.loc[i-1, "position"]
```

So, the code works, but it seems slow, is there any way to speed it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `replace` + `ffill`:

```
df.replace(-1, np.nan).ffill()

   position
0       0.0
1       0.0
2       1.0
3       1.0
4       1.0
5       0.0
```

Replace will convert `-1` to `NaN` values. `ffill` will replace `NaN`s with the value just above it.

Use `.astype` for an integer result:

```
df.replace(-1, np.nan).ffill().astype(int)

   position
0         0
1         0
2         1
3         1
4         1
5         0
```

Don't forget to assign the result back. You could perform the same operation non `position` if need be:

```
df['position'] = df['position'].replace(-1, np.nan).ffill().astype(int)
```

---

Solution using `np.where`:

```
c = df['position'] 
df['position'] = np.where(c == -1, c.shift(), c)
df

   position
0       0.0
1       0.0
2       1.0
3       1.0
4       1.0
5       0.0
```

Comment: @coldspeed I'm not sure what's going on, but I'm not getting the results changed with the provided solutions. If I do `print df`the column still shows the old values with -1

Comment: @churreeero This was a demonstrative example. Please assign the values back like this: `df = df.replace(-1, np.nan).ffill().astype(int)`

Comment: Also I guess that the replace+ffill solution affects to the whole df, not only to df["position"], so probably the np.where solution is better (if it works, right now it doesn't seem to, may be my fault because of something)

Comment: @churreeero Okay, try: `df['position'] = df['position'].replace(-1, np.nan).ffill().astype(int)`?

Comment: Oh, I see, shame on me! I see why it wasn't working the first solution, the dataframe wasn't assigned. But then, I don't get why the np.where solution is not working for me, because it is already assigned: `c=self.df["position"]
            self.df["position"] = np.where(c == -1, c.shift(), c)`

Comment: @coldspeed, sure, thanks a lot, you've been incredibly fast answering. Just for the records, this solution works perfectly: `df['position'] = df['position'].replace(-1, np.nan).ffill().astype(int)`

Comment: @churreeero You're welcome! I made sure to update my answer with that specific solution. Also congrats! You have enough rep to upvote :-)