# Replace string value with previous row value based on conditionals - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to replace the value in the current row based on the previous row given that certain conditions are met.

**Conditions:**

> Current row is 0
>
> Previous row is C
>
> Within Group *(preferred, but will likely work without)*

**Example dataframe similar to mine:**

```
ID  Week value
 4    1     W
 4    2     C
 4    3     0
 4    4     0
24    1     W
24    2     W
24    3     0
24    4     A
```

**Example of what I need it to look like:**

```
ID  Week value
 4    1     W
 4    2     C
 4    3     C
 4    4     C
24    1     W
24    2     W
24    3     0
24    4     A
```

**Questions by others that I cant seem to rework or doesn't quite fit my problem:**

1. [conditional replace based off prior value in same column of pandas dataframe python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877196/conditional-replace-based-off-prior-value-in-same-column-of-pandas-dataframe-pyt)
2. [conditional change of a pandas row, with the previous row value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053712/conditional-change-of-a-pandas-row-with-the-previous-row-value)

**Code to build dataframe similar to mine**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0:'4', 1:'4', 2:'4', 3:'4', 4:'24', 5:'24', 6:'24', 7:'24'}, 'Week': {0:'1', 1:'2', 2:'3', 3:'4', 4: '1', 5:'2', 6:'3', 7:'4'},  'value': {0:'W', 1:'C', 2:'0', 3:'0', 4: 'W', 5:'W', 6:'0', 7:'A'} })
df[['ID', 'Week']] = df[['ID', 'Week']].astype('int')
```

**Poorly worked attempt to solve the problem (throws errors)**

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.value[i] == '0' and df.value[i-1] == 'C':
         df.value[i] = 'C'
     else:
         df.value[i] = df.value[i]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, I would use `np.where` to apply a conditional to a column.  However, given the `.shift()` function, this doesn't work without throwing it into a for loop.  A quick method is using `.replace()`:

```
for row in range(0,len(df)):
    df['value'] = df['value'].replace('0',df['value'].shift(1))
```

If you wish to maintain conditional, you could still utilize `np.where` in a similar fashion.

```
for row in range(0,len(df)):
    df['value'] = np.where((df['value'] == '0') & (df['value'].shift(1) == 'C'), 'C', df['value'])
```

Comment: nice answer, got pretty much the same but the loop threw me, am trying to think of a vectorised solution but no cigar.

Comment: Is this possible to do while grouping by ID?

Comment: Works due to current data structure, but there may be a situation where I have to group by ID

Comment: I added df['ID'].shift() == df['ID'] to make sure replacement doesnt not occur outside of grouping

Answer (score 1):

Not easy to generalize to other situations but for your specific case you can do:

```
is_0 = df['value'] == '0'
is_C_block = df['value'].replace('0', pd.np.nan).fillna(method='ffill') == 'C'

df.loc[is_0 & is_C_block, 'value'] = 'C'
```

Comment: Is this possible to do while grouping by ID?

Comment: Works due to current data structure, but there may be a situation where I have to group by ID

Comment: And what will the grouping do? Some different replacement?

Comment: Prevent referencing replacement outside of grouping. i.e., prevent replacing the first value of individual 24 if it is 0,  if the last value for individual 4 is c

Comment: you could use `df['ID'].shift() != df['ID']` to include an extra condition when a new ID is starteing...